# How do I create a udev rule for my logitech webcam

Tags: 10.04, hardware, webcam, directory

With my webcam plugged in at boot, it always defaults to `/dev/video0` and my TV-card defaults to `/dev/video1`. Tvtime defaults is using `/dev/video0`. I know that I can run Tvtime with the --device option and force it to switch to `/dev/video1`, but if i happen to have my webcam unplugged when I boot, the TV-card becomes video0.

This is very inconvenient, as I have tried to write a "udev" rule, to make the webcam video5 but have not been able to get it to work.

**This is the rule I tried to use:**

```
SUBSYSTEM=="video4linux", BUS=="usb", SYSFS{idvendor}=="046d", SYSFS{idProduct}=="0807", NAME="video5"
```

I saved this in `/etc/udev/rules.d/75-mystuff.rules`, and also tried with a lower number, *15-mystuff.rules*, which didn't work.

I am using Ubuntu 10.04 64bit. Any help to resolve this will be very much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Jan Claesys idea is likely more practical, but...

SYSFS syntax is deprecated or going to be deprecated. You should use ATTRS. The rule should look like:

SUBSYSTEM=="video4linux", BUS=="usb", ATTRS{vendor}=="0x046d", ATTRS{device}=="0x0807", NAME="video5"

Note the 0x to denote a hexadecimal value.

I can't test the rule on my end, but I expect it to work.

Answer (score 1):

If using the --device option is not really a problem, you can probably use the link to the device under `/dev/v4l/by-id/` instead.  I *think* that one should always be the same...